# Credit score for immigrants from SA to Us

Tags: immigration, credit

We are looking to immigrate to the US. I know to get a lease  or any kind of credit you need a credit score. We do have relatives but not directly and I feel like asking them to sign surety is a bit much. How does one that does not have a credit record build one from SA or lease an apartment without a credit score?